# Creating a sparse matrix using R

Tags: r

```
I am trying to create a sparse matrix with my data containing userid, ISBN, and book rating. 

here is my data:

 User.ID       ISBN Book.Rating
 [1,]  276726  155061224           5
 [2,]  276727  446520802           0
 [3,]  276729  521795028           6
 [4,]  276733 2080674722           0
 [5,]  276736 3257224281           8
 [6,]  276737  600570967           6

Here is my code
 UIMatrix <- sparseMatrix(i = final.filtered["User.ID"],
                         j = final.filtered["ISBN"],
                          x = final.filtered["Book.Rating"])

    Error in sparseMatrix(i = final.filtered["User.ID"], j = final.filtered["ISBN"],  : 
      NA's in (i,j) are not allowed
```

I don't have any NA in my data still i am getting this error.Please tell me how to fix this. My sparse matrix contain userid as row, ISBN as column and Bookrating as the corresponding value.

Comment: What is your data? `matrix`, `data.frame`...?

Comment: its a matrix. matrix <- as.matrix(read.csv("BookRating.csv", nrows=50,sep=";",header=TRUE))

Comment: Check the output of `final.filtered["User.ID"]`. You cannot select columns of a matrix this way.

Comment: yes i am getting a NA. So tell me how can i create a sparse matrix avoiding this error

Comment: It is not a matter of creating a sparse matrix here. It a matter how you select columns of your matrix. Simply do `final.filtered[, 1]` and so on.

Comment: Now its showing the correct values of the columns. But i need a little more help when i am trying to print the matrix its giving me error:  object 'UIMatrix' not found.

Comment: What do you mean by "to print the matrix"?

Comment: Mean after following the above syntax for creating the sparse matrix. Now i want to see it.  UIMatrix <- sparseMatrix(i = final.filtered[,1],
                         j = final.filtered[,2],
                         x = final.filtered[,3])

Comment: If you have another question, please post it as such. I would not suggest requesting additional "features" in the comment section.